# labelling bins in each subplots of an histogram chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe,df with 29 rows by 24 columns dimension

```
                     Index             0.0      5.0     34.0 ... 22.0 
          2017-08-03 00:00:00           10        0      10       0
          2017-08-04 00:00:00           20       60    1470      20
          2017-08-05 00:00:00           0        58       0      24
          2017-08-06 00:00:00           0         0     480      24
          2017-09-07 00:00:00           0         0       0      25
                   :                    :         :       :      :
                   :                    :         :       :      :
         2017-09-30 00:00:00
```

I intend to label bins for each subplot representing a column in the histogram chart.I have been able to draw the histogram in each subplot for each column using this code

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,20))
ax = fig.gca()
#Initialize the figure
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
df.hist(ax = ax)
```

However, the labels of the bins of each subplot are far apart and bin labels are not explicitly specified by ranges on the x-axis which is difficult to interpret. I have looked at 
    [Aligning bins to xticks in plt.hist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418552/aligning-bins-to-xticks-in-plt-hist) but it doesnt explicitly solve for labelling bins when subplots are concerned. Any help will be great...

I have also tried this but i get ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
x=[0,40,80,120,160,200,240,280,320]
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,20))
ax = fig.gca()
# Initialize the figure
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
n,bins= plt.hist(df,bins= x)
#labels & axes
plt.locator_params(nbins=8, axis='x')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.title('Daily occurrence',fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('Number of occurrence',fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Frequency',fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.xlim(0,320)
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between the proposed solution and your case. Can you show the attempt where this fails?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  I have edited the question,thanks.

Comment: A useful read: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)